# simple regular expression pattern match

Tags: java, regex

i'm trying to use a regex but i can't find the right result.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(" - ");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("test - test2");
```

It should give me "test"

```
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String fichierPart1 = matcher.group(1);
    }
```

I can't get the result with this code.
Thank you for your help

Comment: Your pattern is to be used in a `.split` method. Just use `"test - test2".split(" - ")`

Answer (score 0):

There is no group 1 - there is only one match, " - ".

An [online regex tester](https://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) makes this much easier to understand.

If you want to get "test", why not do `"test - test".split(" - ")`? This returns an array of the values separated by `-` - `test` and `test` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern should be something difficult: regexes are not the best bet for splitting texts.

Furthermore, regular expressions have their own syntax, that has to be parsed before getting the pattern evaluated. So, that's a lot of work more your app is trying to do uselessly.

I suggest you, as per the comment by @Wiktor Stribiżew, to use `String.split()`. Try just this:

```
for (String part : "test - test2".split(" - ")) {
}
```